# how to fix "all pipe instances are busy" in C# with IPC?

Tags: c#, .net, ipc, remoting

I'm using the IpcChannel in C# to talk between a client and service process.  Usually things work fine

```
 RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
          typeof (x),
          "x",
          WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
```

however on occasion the client after I call

```
 Activator.GetObject(typeof (x),"ipc://x/y");
```

sometimes an exception is thrown "all pipe instance are busy" - i'm not sure what to do with this?

My usage is light, there are only one or two client apps.  I'm guessing under the hood something is wedged up,  but I'm not sure how to diagnose or what to do about it?

thoughts?

Comment: [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and related tools from SysInternals (Microsoft) are usually good starting point on searching for state of kernel objects like pipes and handles.

Comment: This was a bug in an old version of .NET.  Allow Windows Update to update the machine.

Comment: I read that, but the machine is Win8, all the updates for windows and .net have been installed